# C# Creating Purchase system for my application

Tags: c#, wcf, ado.net, cpanel, sdf

I'm building a C# application and would like to sell it for an audience. I would like to upload a database file into a website I own and give serial numbers to be verified first with this database file, once the database store the given serial and the first registered PC then it blocks this serial for other users.

Can anybody guide me on how to make such step during installation time? how I can connect to a remote database on a website to read and write?

Thank you for your time, really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If i understand you, [this](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/43438/Connect-C-to-MySQL) is what your looking for.

Using that you should be able to check a serial against the database.

One way to block the serials for repeated use is to couple a boolean "used" with a serial on each row. Then you can check both if the serial is found in the database, and if the boolean value is false.

[Make sure to keep the input safe](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/SQL_Injection_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet#Primary_Defenses) to prevent SQL injection.

Comment: I do perfect this part of connecting to local database but using sql server compact edition. My question is how to connect to a database located on a website and query it.

Comment: @IbrahemHamdyNaeem 
I don't know too much about that, but in my hosts control panel there is a configuration menu for databases. Note that some hosts don't allow/don't allow multiple databases. For me, I can only have one database on my domain.

Comment: So to clarify: Log in to your web host control panel, find some menu about databases, at the place where you create a new database you should be able to create your account. When connecting you need to use that account, and instead of connecting to localhost you need to connect to your database "host" address. If you look around you should be able to find that address, but for me it's "myDomain.com.mysql"

Comment: Thank you Oscar for taking the time to help me, I find your answer is useful and just watched a video that gives all details of my requirements so I will post it here as an answer beside yours. I have one question, If I give all users the right to access the sql server on CPanel, can they all write the database as well?

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ajwGHb16sgk